# собрать строку из нескольких тхт с определенным названием

Tags: c#

Есть папка, в ней есть тхт файлы. Название тхт файлов таковы `test1,test2,test3,test4`, также есть и другие тхт файлы, у которых имена такие типа:
`text1,text2,text3,text4`. Чтобы не писать 4 `string []file1=File.ReadAllLines("путь к каждому test1");`
и потом через массив, то как прописать чтобы софт брал только `testцифра` файлы, но не брал `text`цифра. Если написать грубо, то будет так, что естественно криво:

```
string []file1=File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users"+SystemInfo.MachineName\Desktop\folder\test"+@"\1.txt"+@"\2.txt"+@"\3.txt"+@"\4.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно получить все файлы в папке подходящие по маске. Для этого можно использовать метод [EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("path/to/directory", "test*.txt");
```

Далее вызвать для загруженных файлов *File.ReadAllLines*

```
var filesContent = files.Select(filePath => File.ReadAllLines(filePath));
```

Comment: нифига не понял

Comment: @glonval, _EnumerateFiles_ возвращает список файлов чьи имена удовлетворяют маске.

Comment: а показать на экране все эти файлы по маске

Comment: @glonval, можешь показать

Comment: все гут........