# Сначала считать 1.txt потом 2.txt

Tags: c#

Есть два txt файла:

В 1.txt

```
1
2
3
```

Во 2.txt то же самое.

Как мне считать с начало первый потом второй то есть когда считался полностью первый то его считывание через `foreach` остановилось, и код начал считывать 2.txt.

Написал такой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace foreach_txt
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string[] files1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\1.txt");
        string[] files2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\2.txt");
        foreach (var lines1 in files1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lines1);
        }
        foreach (var lines2 in files2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lines2);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [собрать строку из нескольких тхт с определенным названием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658698/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%82%d1%85%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: @Grundy я знаю, я спрашивал такой вопрос, но это совсем не то что мне надо

Comment: Если нужно считать последовательно сначала один файл, а затем второй, то и нужно делать последовательно, а не вкладывать один цикл считывания в другой.

Comment: @Bulson перепечатал его так: но он показывает построчно, а мне надо чтобы в одну строку оба файла шли

Comment: Тогда нужно использовать один цикл `for` и по индексу выводить данные из одного, а затем из другого.

Comment: Приведите пример вывода, который вы ожидаете

Comment: Если надо в одну строку, то замени `WriteLine` на `Write`.

Comment: `foreach` **не считывает** данные. что ты имеешь ввиду под _считывание через foreach_?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
foreach (var lines1 in files1)
{
    Console.Write(lines1);
}
foreach (var lines2 in files2)
{
    Console.Write(lines2);
}
```

А так не нужно лишний раз переименовывать:

```
foreach (var lines in files1)
{
    Console.Write(lines);
}
foreach (var lines in files2)
{
    Console.Write(lines);
}
```